# Admin crud - achievable by beginner?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, backend, forms

I have a task where i must implement a relatively involved crud module.

It will have a few different entities which will require a couple of different admin crud forms and the associated navigation items etc.

My question is, is this beyond the abillity of a beginner in Magento?  After reading about it, creating these admin grids etc seems very complicated - although also very repitive in some respects.

Can anyone with experience in creating these say if these are difficult or easy to create and if there are any specific tips?

Comment: It is just a copy-paste, nothing difficult if you understand what are you doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the real question comes down to **whether you're a beginner to programming in general, or to Magento itself.**

I think that admin CRUD is probably the least-understood portion of Magento and sends even accomplished developers into fits of rage. Part of the reason they're so difficult to grok is due to the fact that, in the admin, blocks and layout happen in a different way than they do on the frontend.

Many things, like grid block class file location, are derived from property value settings.

I would say that it's an `Intermediate to Advanced` undertaking - not impossible - but you will find some challenges along the way.

Here is an online module creator tool which creates admin grid views for you for custom tables. This should at least get you heading in the right direction:

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/